# this dynamic sql is working fine from sql command prompt but if executed from sql file then always returns 0, why?

Tags: mysql, prepare

```
delimiter //

drop procedure if exists usp_validateUserLogin;

create procedure usp_validateUserLogin(in t varchar(255), 
in username varchar(255), 
in password varchar(255),out count int)
BEGIN
   set @r=0;
   set @tbl=concat('select count(*) into @r from ',t);
   set @tbl2=concat(@tbl,' where @tbl.username=username and @tbl.password=password');
   prepare pstmt from @tbl2;
   execute pstmt;
   set count=@r;
END//

delimiter ;
```

above code is written in a file and i am executing it from sql command prompt and compiles with no error. when i call this stored procedure it returns every time a zero, although there is only one record which matches input parameter. 
if i execute same statements from sql command prompt itself then its working correctly.

Comment: you need to tell what schema you are supposed to use, the database engine is not supposed to guess it right for you... "use database_name;"

Comment: i am executing the script file right after selecting the intended database, also added first line as "use mydatabase_name"..but getting same output. call usp_validateUserLogin('users','z','123',@count) and then executing select @count prints 0 as output.

Comment: add this line to the stored procedure before prepare the statement (it should let you see what query is being executed) : select 'sql_query:' , @tbl2;

Comment: mysql> select 'sql_query:' , @tbl2;
| sql_query: | select count(*) into @r from users where @tbl.username=username and @tbl.password=password | ............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   set @tbl=concat('select count(*) into @r from ',t, ' t ');
   set @tbl2=concat(@tbl,' where t.username=', username, ' and t.password=', password');
```

and this question could had been avoided if you had printed the sql statement before try to execute it...